# A question of mine, without good answers, about which I don't care anymore

Tags: support, specific-question, unanswered-questions

I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439007/changing-ui-color-in-eclipse) where I got three answers but none was good.

Now I don't care any more about getting an answer to that question (because I have no more need of that, not because I found an answer).

Am I supposed to let it there as it is, to delete it, or what?

Comment: They were good, just not useful to you in particular. I just upvoted all of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Leave it, it belongs to the community now, and someone else can benefit from it.